# Classes in my bin folder got deleted

Tags: java

I have being getting this Error: Could not find or load main class arg when trying to run my java in ecclipse. i also noticed all the classes in my bin folder are no longer there,i can still see my java files in src folder tho. how do i go about fixing this. am guessing my AVG antivirus contributed to this.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click project and select "Refresh" to ensure Eclipse caches of the file system are up-to-date, then select pull-down menu "Project" > "Clean..." to force a clean rebuild.